# Why doesn't this stream & lambda expression work with SpEL declaration?

Tags: spring, spring-el, spring-cache

I'm trying to use a Java 8 stream and lambda expression in a Spring @Cache annotation.

I'm trying to use the following:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "tags", allEntries = true, 
condition = "#entity.getTags().stream().anyMatch(tag -> tag.getId() == null)")
```

It is failing with:

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: 
EL1042E:(pos 40): Problem parsing right operand
```

However, I am able to get it to work if I move the stream into a method on the entity.  The annotation then works as follows without error:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "tags", beforeInvocation=true, allEntries = true, 
condition = "#entity.containsNewTag()")
```

I would prefer not to need the 'containtsNewTag()' method and use the stream directly in the SpEL expression if possible.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Expression Language is defined [in the developer guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions). What you're trying to do isn't supported by the language at the moment. I'd also argue that this is a very weird place to put such code: an isolated method that you can unit test is much better indeed.

Answer (score 9):

Don't let naysayers get in your way, even if they author accepted answers!  :)   You can accomplish your intention with a little creativity! The following syntax (using [Collection Selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-selection) and 'this')

here #root is your entity, and inside the selection, #this refers to a tag.

Example anyMatch:

```
"#root.getTags().?[#this.getId() == null].size() > 0"
```

Example allMatch:

```
"#root.getTags().?[#this.getId() == null].size() eq #root.getTags().size()"
```

Comment: This is just for filtering, what about mapping?