# value annotation with wildcards for file name starting with string in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I have below value in my `application.properties` file

```
input.file-path=c:\\temp\\data
```

In that path I have two files:

- Students_Input_20221212.dat
- Workers_Input_20221212.dat

is there a way using `@Value` annotation to get each of the files by using the start with string? Something like below:

```
@Value("${input.file-path}/Students_Input_*.dat")
private String inputFileStudents;

@Value("${input.file-path}/Workers_Input_*.dat")
private String inputFileWorkers;
```

So I have:

```
inputFileStudents = "c:\\temp\\data\\Students_Input_20221212.dat"
inputFileWorkers = "c:\\temp\\data\\Workers_Input_20221212.dat"
```

Comment: possibly a starting point toward a solution, " Accessing Beans  You could call bean methods within the @Value expression through SpEL.  @Value("#{someService.someMethod()}") private String valueFromAnotherBean; Code language: CSS (css)This way, You could call other beans or bean.fields to populate values. For this to work, The other bean must be initialized."  https://springhow.com/a-guide-to-value-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Finally found:

[**`[PathMatching]ResourcePatternResolver`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html)!

##### Consider:

- spring-boot:3 starter (web)
- properties:

  ```properties
  # existing path (win):
  input.file=C:\\temp\\data
  # file filter (ant path matcher):
  input.students.filter=Students_Input_*.dat
  input.workers.filter=Workers_Input_*.dat
  ```

##### Testing time:

```java
// ...
import java.util.Arrays;
// import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver; // !!
// ...
@Bean
InitializingBean patternResolverShowCase( /* <- just a demo ... */
  /*@Autowired*/ ResourcePatternResolver resolver, /* <- autowire/@value "anywhere"(in spring beans)... */
  @Value("${input.file}") String folder, /* <- alternative for @Value: (type-safe) @ConfigurationProperties ;) */
  @Value("${input.students.filter}") String studentsFilter, /* < filter1 */
  @Value("${input.workers.filter}") String workersFilter /* < filter2 */
) {
  return () -> { // <- initializingBean - lambda..
    System.err.println( // <- just a demo...
      Arrays.toString( // ..do whatever you like with:
        resolver.getResources("file:" + folder + "/" + studentsFilter)
      )
    );
    System.err.println(
      Arrays.toString( // ... :
        resolver.getResources("file:" + folder + "/" + workersFilter)
      )
    );
  };
}
```

##### With SpEL

Declaring (assigning name and implementation class, otherwise we get a "nameless default"):

```java
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver; // !

// ...
@Bean
ResourcePatternResolver rssResolver() {
    return new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
}
```

..we can also just (SpEL):

```java
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource; // !
// ...
@Value("#{@rssResolver.getResources('file:'+'${input.file}'+'/'+'${input.students.filter}')}") Resource[] studentFiles;
@Value("#{@rssResolver.getResources('file:'+'${input.file}'+'/'+'${input.workers.filter}')}") Resource[] workerFiles;
// do whatever you like with'em (in spring) ...
```

##### Explanations

- above link...
- properties, path separator handling and adjustment: to your needs/suits.
- `@Value("#{...}")` SpEL expression (in a `@Value` ...).
- `@rssResolver` refers to "rssResolver" bean.
- plus:

#### Original answer:

> <del>Wildcards will be hard (from `@Value`), but</del> this (wiring a
> directory into bean context) is easy-peasy:
>
> ##### Properties:
>
> ```properties
> # existing path (win):
> myFolder=C:\\temp\\data
> # file filter (regex!):
> myFileFilter=^test.*\.txt$
> ```
>
> ##### Test
>
> ```java
> @Bean InitializingBean fileResourceShowCase(/* <- just a demo */
>     @Value("${myFolder}") FileSystemResource rss1, /* <- org.springframework.core.io */
>     @Value("#{T(java.nio.file.Path).of('${myFolder}')}") Path path, /* <- java.nio */
>     @Value("#{new java.io.File('${myFolder}')}") File file, /* <- java.io */
>     @Value("${myFileFilter}") String filter /* <- custom/extra */
> ) {
>   return () -> { // 3 ways to access java.io.File:
>     System.err.println(rss1.getFile());
>     System.err.println(path.toFile());
>     System.err.println(file);
>     // apply the filter:
>     File[] files = file.listFiles((f) -> f.getName().matches(filter));
>     for (File f : files) {
>       System.err.println(f);
>     }
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> ##### Explanations:
>
> - `@Value("${myFolder}") FileSystemResource rss1`: access the folder as a (spring) `FileSystemResource` just by it's name (represented by
>   `${myFolder}` placeholder). [**prefer!**]
> - `@Value("#{T(java.nio.file.Path).of('${myFolder}')}") Path path`: SpEL expression for (static) `Path.of(myFolder)` (where `${myFolder}`
>   is resolved as above).
> - `@Value("#{new java.io.File('${myFolder}')}") File file`: SpEL expression for: `new File(myFolder)` ...
>
> ##### Links:
>
> - (spring)[Resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#resources)
> - [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions)
>
> ##### Don'ts
>
> Unfortunately we *cannot* do this with SpEL:
>
> ```java
> @Value("""
>   #{
>     T(java.nio.file.Path).of('${myFolder}')
>     .toFile()
>     .listFiles(
>       (f)->f.getName().matches('${myFileFilter}')
>     )
>   }
> """) File[] files; // -> EL1042E: Problem parsing right operand ;(;(
> ```

see: [Why doesn't this stream & lambda expression work with SpEL declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32132214/592355)

> *Neither* this:
>
> ```java
> @Value("${myFolder}/**") FileSystemResource[] rssArr // -> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index ...
> ```

... the last (`@Value("${myFolder}/**")`) approach brought me to: https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+antpathmatcher+filesystem ;)